# Why does installing xlwings over the terminal produce an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, xlwings

I am relatively new to Python and I am just doing a private project right now. For that I want to install xlwing to be able to run a python code from Excel. However it seems I can not install it. I try to install via:

```
C:\Users\Rafi>python -m pip install --user xlwings
```

as I installed all my other stuff.

Now when I put that into the terminal it shows me the (long) error following. However, I cant find a solution, whatever I try, maybe you guys have some suggestions?

```
***Running setup.py install for comtypes ... error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: 'C:\Users\Rafi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Rafi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xfdrq0ph\comtypes\setup.py'"'"'; __file='"'"'C:\Users\Rafi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xfdrq0ph\comtypes\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Rafi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qtr4pqm3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= cwd: C:\Users\Rafi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xfdrq0ph\comtypes\ Complete output (276 lines): running install running build running build_py creating build creating build\lib creating build\lib\comtypes copying comtypes\automation.py -> build\lib\comtypes copying comtypes\connectionpoints.py -> build\lib\comtypes copying<br/>
.<br/>
.<br/>
.<br/>
error: error in setup script: command 'bdist_wininst' has no such option 'install_script'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Rafi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Rafi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xfdrq0ph\comtypes\setup.py'"'"'; _file='"'"'C:\Users\Rafi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xfdrq0ph\comtypes\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Rafi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qtr4pqm3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes from installing a dependency of xlwings: comtypes.

A quick google search revealed that your issue could be caused by an old version of wheels. Upgrade wheels like this and try again:

```
pip install --upgrade wheel
```

Comment: Hi Felix!

Thanks so much, I just googled the general error in installing xlwings and didn't know what to specifically google, thank you so much:)

Comment: If it solved your issue, can you accept the answer @Rafii1?

Comment: Actually I have another problem, my code says that it cannot find a module named "win32api". I googled the problem and tried all the solutions I could find without success. I tried installing it seperately over the command terminal.

I think it may be the problem that my python is 64-bit but win32api is for a 32 bit Python? I tried to search for a 64 bit version but couldnt find one that worked for me

Comment: You need to install `pip install pywin32` - this is for both 64bit and 32bit systems.

Comment: I already tried that and I get the message that `Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\---`
However when I try to run a code with xlwings it tells me that it cant find win32api